# React Input Type not editable

Tags: reactjs

I was adding dynamic values to the input file in react then I tried to edit that but it not at all editable.

```
var shop_profile_data = this.state.data.DETAILS;

<input id="shopname" className="inputMaterial"  value={shop_profile_data.NAME} type="text" required/>
```

Please give me the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 58):

Since `value` is always rendered with the same value (`shop_profile_data.NAME`) nothing is able to change.  By setting `value` property you are making `input` a Controlled Component.

You need to add an `onChange` event and then set the `shop_profile_data.NAME` to a different value.  Then the value of the `input` will change.

If you only want to set the initial value of the `input`, use `defaultValue` property ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#default-value)).  `defaultValue` will set the initial value, but then allow the value to be changed.

For more read about [Controlled vs Uncontrolled Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

Comment: But If I set defaultValue={shop_profile_data.SHOP_NAME}  it was showing null only

Comment: SHOP_NAME?  I thought it was just name?

Comment: defaultValue={shop_profile_data.NAME}  Sorry this was just name only

Comment: Word of caution: defaultValue causes weird, hard to track down, bugs; and it doesn't let you render based on the input's current value, or update the value if you get new data.

Answer (score 46):

Try using `defaultValue` instead of `value`, `defaultValue` will set the value and also editable.
The code will look like this:

```
<input id="shopname" className="inputMaterial"  defaultValue={shop_profile_data.NAME} type="text" required/>
```

reference: [Uncontrolled Components – React](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values)

Answer (score 18):

The below code show how we can make an input tag editable in reactjs.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

    class App extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: 2016
        }  
      }
      _handleChangeEvent(val) {
        return val;
      }
      render(){
        return (
          <div>
            <input type='number' 
                   onChange={()=>{this._handleChangeEvent(this.state.data);}} 
                   defaultValue={this.state.data} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```