# React Redux form input editing returns error message of an uncontrolled input

Tags: reactjs, redux

**React Redux** form input editing returns error message of an uncontrolled input

Below code uses **react redux** to display a record in a form input from database and it worked fine. when I tried to edit the form input for **lastname** it does not edit but rather
it displays error

**A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. 
Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.**

here is how am displaying the result that i want to edit in a form input

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" value={pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>  



      handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}

/*
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
*/
```

**below is the full react redux code**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { userActions } from '../_actions';

class Edit1 extends React.Component {



constructor(props) {
        super(props);

this.state = {
name: '',
lastName: '',

        };
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);  


        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    componentDidMount() {    
this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll_Rec());


    }

handleChange = (name) => (event) => {
   this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
}

/*
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }
*/




    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

       //process form submit
    }







    render() {
        const { pg1, pgs1 } = this.props;
        return (




 <div className="list">
                <div >

Name: {pgs1.items1 &&  this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}<br />

<input type="text" className="form-control" value={pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>                     

            </div>

</div>

        );
    }
}



function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { pgs1 } = state;
    const { pg1 } = state;
    return {
        pg1,
        pgs1
    };
}


const connectedEdit1 = connect(mapStateToProps)(Edit1);
export { connectedEdit1 as Edit1 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last what solve my problem of input form not editing was replacing form input value{} with defaultValue{} option. I leverage solutions/answer posted by Solanki here [React Input Type not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067562/react-input-type-not-editable)

Not this anymore

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" value={pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

but this solve my problem

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" defaultValue={pgs1.items1 && this.props.pgs1.items1[0].lastName}  onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

With implementation of  defaultValue{} I can now edit form values all the time.