# How to fill an input correctly with a value = ""?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

When I put value="" inside the input, it does not allow me to fill the username and the password.

Without the value="" it allows me to fill, with the value="" nothing happens

```
{/* User */}
<div class="input-group form-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
</div>
{/* Senha */}
<div class="input-group form-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
   </div>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
</div>
```

The input field has to allow me to fill username and password.

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-only platform. Please rewrite your question or it will be quickly removed.

Comment: Sorry... when I put "value =" inside "<input>", it does not allow me to fill in the name and the password.

Without the "value =" it allows me to fill, with the "value =" nothing happens.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: what does `handleChange` do?

Comment: Please translate your question. Do not just put it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "defaultValue" instead of "value" similar to:
[React Input Type not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067562/react-input-type-not-editable)

```
{/* User */}
<div class="input-group form-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
   </div>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="username" defaultValue={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
</div>
{/* Senha */}
<div class="input-group form-group">
   <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
   </div>
   <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="password" defaultValue={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
</div>
```