# How to pass Props() value into setState() to make modal form editable using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-state

I am creating my `blog` where an `user` can able to `edit` his/her blogs. 
Here I am popping the data into a modal to make this `edit`..

**So after all debugging and a better thinking I have figure this out . This is my updated working code for `modal`**

Thank you for your time.

//blog.js

```
class Blogs extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {
                modal: false,
                justClicked: null,
                activePage: 1,
                requiredItem : null,
                _id: '',
                blog_short_desc:'',
                blog_name: '',
                blog_desc: '',
                blog_image_link: '',
                blog_by: '',
                blog_by_author: ''
            };
            this.handleOpenDialog = this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this);
            this.handleCloseDialog = this.handleCloseDialog.bind(this);
            this.replaceModalItem = this.replaceModalItem.bind(this);
            this.onTodoChange = this.onTodoChange.bind(this);
        }

    static propTypes = {
        getBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        updateBlog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        resume: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        loading: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }

    toggle = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            modal: !this.state.modal
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getBlog();  
    }

    replaceModalItem(id, blog_short_desc, blog_name , blog_desc, blog_image_link, blog_by, blog_by_author) {
        this.setState({
          modal: true,
          requiredItem: id,
          _id: id,
          blog_short_desc: blog_short_desc,
          blog_name: blog_name,
          blog_desc: blog_desc,
          blog_image_link: blog_image_link,
          blog_by: blog_by,
          blog_by_author: blog_by_author
        });
    }

    onTodoChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ 
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value 
        });
    }

    onSubmit = (e, id) => {

        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedBlog = {
            blog_short_desc: this.state.blog_short_desc,
            blog_name: this.state.blog_name,
            blog_desc: this.state.blog_desc,
            blog_image_link: this.state.blog_image_link,
            blog_by:  this.props.auth["user"]._id,
            blog_by_author: this.props.auth["user"].name
        }

        //update blog via updateblog action
        this.props.updateBlog(id, updatedBlog);
        alert("Blog updated successfully!");
        e.target.reset();
        this.toggle();
        window.location.reload();
    }

    handleOpenDialog(id) {
        this.setState({
          openDialog: true,
          OpenEditDialog: true,
          justClicked: id

        });
    }

    handleCloseDialog() {
    this.setState({
        openDialog: false
    });
    }

    onDeleteBlogClick = (id) => {
        this.props.deleteBlog(id);
    };

    handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
        this.setState({activePage: pageNumber});
    }

    render(){
        const { blogs, loading} = this.props.resume;
        const {  user, isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;
        const itemsPerPage = 6; 
        let activeBlogs = blogs.slice (itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage - itemsPerPage, itemsPerPage * this.state.activePage);
        return(
            <Container>
            {loading ? (
            <div><Loading/></div>
            ) : (
                <div>
                    {/* blog modal */}
                    <BlogModal />

                    {/* card dialog */}
                    <BlogData blogs={blogs} user={this.props.auth} handleCloseDialog={this.handleCloseDialog}  {...this.state} toggle={this.toggle}/>

                    {/* edit card dialog */}
                    <EditBlog onTodoChange={this.onTodoChange}  {...this.state} toggle={this.toggle} onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>

                    <Grid style={{padding: 0}}  className="blog-grid">
                        {activeBlogs.map((item, i) => (
                            <Cell key={item._id} data-id={item._id} className="blog-grid-cell">   
                                <Card shadow={5} className="cards-grid">
                                    {item.blog_image_link ?
                                        (<CardTitle style={{color: '#fff', height: '200px',
                                        width: 'auto', backgroundImage: `url(${item.blog_image_link})`, backgroundPosition: 'center',
                                        backgroundSize: 'cover',
                                        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'}}></CardTitle>) :

                                        (<CardTitle className="card-title-image"></CardTitle>
                                        )
                                    }

                                    <CardText>
                                        <b>{item.blog_short_desc}</b>
                                    </CardText>

                                    <CardActions border>
                                        <p className="block-data-details">
                                            <Button className="blog-read-me-button col-4" onClick={this.handleOpenDialog.bind(this, item._id)}>Read </Button> 

                                            { isAuthenticated === true && (item.blog_by === user._id) ? 
                                            <span className="col=8">

                                            <Button className="remove-btn-blog-post"
                                            color="danger"
                                            size="sm"
                                            onClick= {this.onDeleteBlogClick.bind(this, item._id)} title="Delete Blog">
                                                &times;
                                            </Button> 
                                            <a className="btn edit-btn-blog-post" href="#" 
                                            onClick={this.replaceModalItem.bind(this, item._id, item.blog_short_desc, item.blog_name, item.blog_desc, item.blog_image_link, item.blog_by, item.blog_by_author )}  title="Edit Blog">
                                                <i className="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            </span> : null }
                                        </p>
                                        <p style={{ fontWeight:'bold'}}>By-{item.blog_by_author} <span style={{float:'right',}}>{Moment(item.date).format('Do MMMM YYYY')}</span></p> 
                                    </CardActions>
                                </Card>  
                            </Cell>  
                        ))} 
                    </Grid>
                </div> 
                )}
                <Pagination
                    activePage={this.state.activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={6}
                    totalItemsCount={blogs.length}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                    onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}
                    itemClass='page-item'
                    linkClass='page-link'
                />
            </Container>
        ) 
   }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    auth: state.auth,
    loading: state.apiCallsInProgress > 0
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getBlog, deleteBlog, updateBlog }) (Blogs);
```

//Edit.js

```
    const EditBlog = ({ toggle, onTodoChange, onSubmit, ...state}) => {

    return( 
        <span>
            <Modal 
                isOpen = {state.modal && state.requiredItem === state._id}
                toggle = {()=>this.toggle(state._id)}    
            >
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}  style={{fontWeight: "bold"}}>
                    Edit your blog {state.blog_name}
                </ModalHeader>
                <ModalBody>
                    <Form onSubmit={e => onSubmit(e, state._id )}>
                        <FormGroup>
                            <Label for="blogHeading">Blog Heading</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="blog_short_desc" id="blogHeading" placeholder="Update one liner"
                            onChange={onTodoChange} defaultValue={state.blog_short_desc}/>
                            <Label for="blogName">Blog Name</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="blog_name" id="blogName" placeholder="Update blog name"
                            onChange={onTodoChange} defaultValue={state.blog_name}/>
                            <Label for="desc1">Description </Label>
                            <Input type="textarea" name="blog_desc" id="desc1" placeholder="Update your blog"
                            onChange={onTodoChange} defaultValue={state.blog_desc}/>
                            <Label for="imageUrl">Image Url</Label>
                            <Input type="text" name="blog_image_link" id="imageUrl" placeholder="Update image url (Optional)"
                            onChange={onTodoChange} defaultValue={state.blog_image_link}/>
                            <Button
                                color="dark"
                                style={{marginTop: '2rem'}}
                                block
                            >Edit blog</Button>
                        </FormGroup>
                </Form>
                </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
        </span>

    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    resume: state.resume,
    auth: state.auth
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updateBlog })(EditBlog);
```

//CurrentUI of working `edit`

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help me to sort out this ?

Comment: I have updated my code from github. https://github.com/tanmoysarkar/MERN_blog

Comment: Why are you generating modals in loop. You should set *editingIndex* in state of your blog.js, whenever editingIndex is set, open your modal and pass data of editingIndex to Edit.js.

Comment: Hi @gautamits  thanks for your time. do you mind to give me an example or so with my code. It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Can you please host some sandbox. It will be easier to work with.

Comment: I tried this in https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tanmoysarkar/MERN_blog . but it comes with errors. :/

Comment: @TanmoySarkar if you can get the sandbox working with the uneditable issue you're asking about, I'll edit it to show you what I suggested in my answer. I think your build commands aren't being run, and you assume the existence of environment variables (NODE_ENV) that you aren't setting.

Comment: @Aaron by changing `value` with `defaultValue` it is editbale. but as I updated in my question other state values are empty. If you could look at this to make it proper by with your idea. It will be helpful.

Comment: @Aaron I tried to make codesandbox working but I am unable to sort it out why its not working here in `codesandbox` but it is working in `localhost`

Comment: @Aaron do you mind to look github . Can you do so it will be very helpful to me. Kind of stuck for a while .

Comment: @TanmoySarkar as I said in my answer, the problem is that your `onTodoChange` updates the state, but that state isn't passed into the input values inside `EditBlog`, only values from the `blogs` prop are. I don't feel like cloning, running, editing, and submitting a PR for your repo, so if you can't get the sandbox to work, then try out the changes in your repo, commit them to a branch, and tell me how it goes.

Comment: Hi @Aaron I am fully agree with your views. Neverthless I will try to do so. thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure it out with

1. `OnClick` of `edit` button I passed all required data along with it.
   So, my `replaceModalItem()` binds all data together in `setState()`
2. In `replaceModalItem` i called those data and set it to `setState()`.
3. In `Edit.js` I have called all the `state` values.

Hence getting all the required values in input field setting it with `defaultValue`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, the uneditable bug is caused by using "value" props for your input in modal inside of "defaultValue". If you use value, you are always giving it the value of initial props. Use default value. Using defaultValue makes it a controlled component. Read more on  [Stackoverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36067615/905494). Change that and see next issues if any.

Second, ensure you avoid [UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops). Looking at your componentWillRecieveProps method, what is said in the documentation may be at play:

"Calling this.setState() generally doesn’t trigger UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps()."

Update:

Remove the componentWillReceiveProps method. submit should work. And ensure user is authenticated.

Comment: Hi Tksilicon thank you fot your time and effort. but As in this case I am unable to set the `setState()` value on click edit button it creates problem inside edit compoenent. If you could look what I can chaneg to set setState() value then may be It can help me more. Please have a look of `github` code may e that is better explained.

Comment: Are you able to edit the modal now? If not change value of input to default input.

Comment: `defaultValue` is helping to change . But if user is not making any edit then value is empty.

Comment: I will look at it.

Comment: I have updated my scrren shot with current status. Hope it will help you a bit.

Comment: If state is empty then it will create a bug on `onSubmit` . What you suggest so that all exceptional cases can be handled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212585/discussion-between-tanmoy-sarkar-and-tksilicon).

Comment: do you mean `componenet will receiveprops` As i didn't apply compoent will update

Comment: could you please edit your answer a bit. so that I can upvote yours answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like your `onTodoChange` function is setting state on the parent `Blogs` component, but that state doesn't make it back to the input values. Instead, the parent passes a `blogs` prop into `EditBlogs`, and since `onTodoChange` never affects `blogs`, the input's `value` remains unchanged.

This means your inputs' `onChange` event values (`e.target.value`) never make it back to the inputs' `value` attribute, so the input doesn't actually change values.

Since the `blog_` values in `state` and `onTodoChange` are all local to the edit form, I recommend moving those down to that level.. `Blogs` doesn't need to know about that stuff, and it'll simplify things - `onTodoChange` will set event values into `state`, which will flow right back into the inputs as values.

Your `blogs` prop should only set the initial `state`.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you for your time. Do you mind if you give me a example code with my my current state. May be this is something will be help me ot understand the code more. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When a user is editing their blog, take their blog information and create an object like this

```
userBlogData={
  blog_heading: 'users blog heading',
  blog_name: 'users blog name',
  description: 'users blog description',
  image_url: 'users blog image url',
}
```

Update the modal form based on these objects. For example:

```
<input name="blog_heading" value={blog_heading} ... />
```

After the user have edited the object you can make an update request on your server and call the get function at the same time for updating the blogs. You can keep the update function on the edit component. But the get function will be passed as a props.

Hope This Helps

This should give you the idea...........................

```
    // Edit Component

    this.state = {
       blog_name:this.props.data.blog_name
    }
    onBlogUpdate = () => {
      let payload = this.state
      API CALL...
     }
    ...
     render(){
        return(
            <input value={this.state.blog_name} name='blog_name' onChange={...} ... />
        )
     }
```

Comment: Hi Rakib... Hope you are doing good. thank you for your time. As 
<EditBlog blogs={blogs} user={this.props.auth} 
                onTodoChange={this.onTodoChange}  {...this.state} toggle={this.toggle}
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}/>

this is my edit blog child class, which i am passing then how could i call when edit is happeing.

Comment: And what changes I should made in `editchild` component ?

Comment: Actually you dont need to be able to tell if the edit is happening or not. Just populate the state with

    activeBlogs.map

And set the input name and value from them. When user click edit blog then you update the blog with updated data from state inside Edit compoennt

Comment: Edit is not happeing because datta is passing from props which is `iimutable`. And I am unable to set ste setState() value. which is my ultimate goal so that I can set the state value insode input field.

Comment: As `codesandbox` is not working else I caould beeter explain my propblem . Although if you want you can see the issue in github.

Comment: You just have to store the data into the state of Edit component. There you will have changeable data.

Comment: I have updated the code. Hope you get the process from that...