# React Input type not able to insert any data

Tags: reactjs, controlled-component

In my React component I have used input type; but somehow it is not going to to editable anyhow.

I have checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067562/react-input-type-not-editable/41338877) as well but not able to trace the solution.

```js
const Index = ({
  const [editable, setEditable] = useState(false)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setEmail(data.primaryEmail)
    }
  }, [data])

  return (
    <Emails 
      data={data} 
      changeHandle={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      emailName={email}
    />
  )
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Index)


const Emails = ({
    data,
    changeHandle,
    emailName
  }) => {

return (
  <Card>
    <React.Fragment>
      <tr key={email}>
        <td className="text-gray-6 pl-0 pb-0">
          <input className="mb-2" value={emailName} onChange={e => changeHandle(e)} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </React.Fragment>
  </Card>
)
}

export default Emails
```

What's am I doing in this above code ?

Comment: This seems like a overcomplicated way to control an input, and your `changeHandle` doesn't appear to actually save the new value anywhere.

Comment: So, where can I exactly utilise the `changeHandle`  to handle the editable field ?

Comment: A simple managed input would generally look something like this: `<input value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />` I'm not sure I understand the need for you to use multiple states and setter functions. [React controlled components documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the email as a prop, but in your Emails element, it just takes 'data' and 'channgeHandle'. Try to add email as a prop:

```
const Emails = ({ data, email, changeHandle }) => {
  return (
    <Card>
        <tr key={email}>
          <td className="text-gray-6 pl-0 pb-0">
            <input className="mb-2" value={email} onChange={e => changeHandle(e)} />
          </td>
        </tr>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

After that, pass the setEmail to the changeHandle prop:

```
return (
    <Emails 
      data={data} 
      changeHandle={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      emailName={email}
    />
  )
```

Beside this, apparently your data prop is not used at any moment, so I don't see the utility for it.

Comment: I passed the `emailName` as props but still it is not going to editable. Please review updated question.

Comment: In your changeHandle prop use the setEmail to change the state of the email.

Comment: I am managing that `setEmail` into another component. But still it is not working.

Comment: Your changeHandle prop is just console.log the changed value. Because of that, there's no way this works.

Comment: Ohh, that I used for just check the log, but nyws updated that potion as well. But still n change at all :(